# Display HashMap<String, Object> in Angular6 received from Rest API

Tags: java, angular, spring, rest

I'm trying to display the content of HashMap received from my controller, however I get an empty map.

this is my controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "getAllUsers")
public HashMap<String, Object> getAllUsers(@RequestBody String s)
{
    List<User> list = userRepository.getAll(s);

    HashMap<String, Object> userList = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    userList.put("list", list);
    userList.put("total", list.size());

    return userList;
}
```

and this is my angular code:

```
 getUsers() {

    this.userService.getUsers("canada").subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data); // this returns an empty object
        data.forEach((value: string, key: string) => { // returns an error which is forEach is not a function
            console.log(key, value);
        });
        this.userList = data; // empty
        console.log(this.userList);
    });
}
```

this is my api service:

```
let URL = "api/v1";
getUsers(country: String): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(URL + "getAllUsers", country);
}
```

I want to know how to manipulate and iterate the HashMap received from my controller. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to `http.get()` instead of `http.post()` first read about how http protocols works then use them.

Comment: Is your URL complete? What you did show was "api/v1/getAllUsers". Did you check the response of the call in your network tab?

Comment: Are you sure, `List<User> list = userRepository.getAll(s);` has data for value `canada`? Also, `forEach` on `data` won't work at front end as its not of type `Array`, you need to iterate it over `data.list`.

Comment: yes there is data for the value of canada, i can get the total but not the data itself

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is assuming the response as an `Object` of type `any` instead of a `Map`, so Try this:

```
Object.entries(data).forEach((value: string, key: string) => { 
      console.log(key, value);
});
```

Comment: I don't think that's a problem. You can still declare `any` and get the data from the REST endpoint. The problem here is that there is nothing returned from the REST controller.

Comment: but you cannot apply `forEach` method on `any`

Comment: and there is no such rule that you cannot retrieve data from a POST request, it is just standard to use these methods for specific purpose but their is no such limitation

Answer (score 1):

The point here is not HashMap iteration but your are getting empty response data even here.

```
 this.userService.getUsers("canada").subscribe((data) => {
       console.log(data);         // this returns an empty object
```

Add **@ResponseBody**

```
 @PostMapping(value = "getAllUsers")
 @ResponseBody
 public HashMap<String, Object> getAllUsers(@RequestBody String s)
```

Now coming to iteration once you get the response which is not empty there are multiple ways to iterate map.

```
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {

    console.log(key, data[key]);
  });
```

=> Better to use Http convention of using get to fetch data over post. Although data will still be received in Post but prefer get().

Comment: yes as you said the problem is in the controller side, I get empty data but I get the total, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a `POST` request but in your use case you should use the `GET` http method in order to retrieve a resource. `POST` http method is used to add a resource. You have to change your controller to use  `@GetMapping()`

```
@GetMapping("/getAllUsers")
public HashMap<String, Object> getAllUsers(@PathVariable String s)
{
    List<User> list = userRepository.getAll(s);

    HashMap<String, Object> userList = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    userList.put("list", list);
    userList.put("total", list.size());

    return userList;
}
```

You should also change your parameter to that controller from  `@RequestBody` to `@PathVariable`

> `@PathVariable` annotation is used to receive bind the URI variable to the method
>   parameter.
>
> `@RequestBody` annotation binds the content sent in (POST / PUT)
>   request body with the annotated variable. (Generally, you can only use
>   @RequestBody for the requests which can have 'body' content e.g. POST
>   or PUT.)

You can read about HTTP Methods [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).